# laravel eloquent query orWhere

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In Normal PHP i have a sql query

```
$q = 'shojib'; or $q = '01913711...'; or $q = 'House 23...';

select * from member where LoginName like '%$q%' or mobile like '%$q%' or  ConnectionAdderss like '%$q%' order by LoginName LIMIT 10;
```

i want to write this query in laravel.
Please help me.

i am using SoftDeletingTrait in laravel Member Model

```
Member::where('zone', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
            ->orWhere('login_name', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
            ->orWhere('mobile', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
            ->orderBy('login_name')
            ->take('100')
            ->get();
```

But it will return all data from database with deleted_at is not null;

it should return only those data whose deleted_at is null;

Comment: Your query should only return items that have NOT ben deleted.  To return deleted items, you have to use `onlyTrashed` or `withTrashed`.

Comment: it  returns all deleted data and not deleted data both. But it should only return not deleted data

Answer (score 1):

You should write the query as below

```
Member::onlyTrashed()->where('zone', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
        ->orWhere('login_name', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
        ->orWhere('mobile', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
        ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
        ->orderBy('login_name')
        ->take('100')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

After certain times i have found solution

It should be

```
$members = Member::where(function($query) use ($key)
        {
            $query->where('zone', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
                    ->orWhere('login_name', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
                    ->orWhere('contact_number', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
                    ->orWhere('sms_comn', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
                    ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
                    ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$key.'%');
        })
        ->take('100')
        ->orderBy('login_name', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```